# Detecting when a cell's detail-disclosure button has been clicked (when using a custom cell XIB)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

```
if (cell == nil)       // 1
{                      // 2
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TVCell" owner:self options:nil];  // 3
   cell = tvCell;      // 4
   self.tvCell = nil;  // 5
}                      // 6
```

There's some code from an Apple example of using your own "custom cell XIB" to create cells in a UITableView.

It appears to work... but I think I would do better to actually *understand* what is being done there.

- Why isn't the following assigning the value *to* something?

  ```
  cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TVCell" owner:self options:nil];
  ```

  (In fact, `cell` and `tvCell` aren't being used at all.)
- Why is line #4 assigning using `tvCell` when nothing has been put it in at all, yet?
- Why is line #5 nulling out the `tvCell` that I need?
- Why is this line using assign, not retain?

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *tvCell;
  ```

About the only thing I can't get working correctly is when I put a disclosure-button on my custom cell XIB.  Is there a way for me to detect when the user has clicked on it?  (Hopefully, without using 100s of TAGs.)

Answer (score 22):

I haven't played with XIBs for cells, but I don't see why you couldn't still use `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`.